# Android portrait and landscape layouts

Tags: android, layout, landscape, portrait

I have the following layout:

[image]

I need the following layout in portrait mode:

[image]

But instead of that I obtain the following one that I don't know how to modify it:

[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `layout-land` folder in `res` folder and create `xml` with the same name in this folder.

Answer (score 14):

Fastest way for Android Studio 3.x.x

1.Go to the design tab of the activity layout

2.At the top you should press on the orientation for preview button, there is a option to create a landscape layout (check image), a new folder will be created as your xml layout file for that particular orientation

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could create a seperate Layout for Landscape mode.Just name it the name as your current layout but make sure to add it in the folder layout-land.

Right click on `res - layout` and then `Add New` and for the folder write `layout-land`. Name should be - as said before - the same as your current layout.

[image]

When now changing the orientation to landscape, Android will use this layout.

Answer (score 2):

Just create `layout-land` folder near layout folder and create xml with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

No need to create layout-land. Google has an open sourced [FlexBox Layout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) that works adaptive on screen size /orientation changes like CSS.
Have a look at google's [developer](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/02/build-flexible-layouts-with.html) site for examples.